# Multiple instances of same program in Docker

Tags: docker, virtualization

I have a Java program which simulates a protocol I have made myself. It binds to a given IP address and port number on the machine it is running on. I'm looking to run multiple instances of this program on the same machine which has multiple network cards. Is this possible using Docker (a colleague has suggested this to me but don't know much about it)? My other plan was to run multiple VMs on the machine with bridge interface but I feel this is a waste of resource compared to using Docker instead (based on what I've read about it, still having a hard time grasping the idea).

Once executed, the program runs in the background like a daemon waiting for messages/packets and can be stopped by killing the process.

Comment: This should be possible even *without* docker just by binding your Java application to different local addresses. No real need for any sort of containerization/virtualization. So sure, you can do it with Docker, too.

Comment: If the question is: can this be achieved with Docker, yes... yes it can.

Answer (score 0):

As several commenters noted, there is no reason you can't run multiple instances of your program as containers on a system, just as well as you could probably do it outside of containers as well (given you have a multiple IP addresses available for binding your service port).

The question is probably more one of design. How are you wanting to distribute traffic destined for your Java service application? If you actually want one per physical IP address, then you could run the containers with [`--network=host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) and directly bind your application to a specific IP, probably with some directive/flag to direct that instance to a specific IP. By default Docker will create a bridge network on your system and containers will start with a private network IP and exposing each one on a host port will be up to your [port binding configuration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) for that container. Obviously `iptables` or some kind of higher-level fronting proxy could be used to do any custom routing of traffic from your multiple physical network addresses to the container networks as desired.